# Which BusyBox is legitimate on Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, busybox

[BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net) is a collection of *nix utilities. I am attempting to install it via the Play Store (I've had a lot of trouble in the past trying to cross-compile BusyBox).

The problem I am having: there are six or eight apps using that name, and I cannot tell which (if any) is legitimate. The desktop search is [search?q=busybox](http://play.google.com/store/search?q=busybox), but it only lists about half compared to what's listed on the device using the Play Store app.

I spent some time searching on XDA and Android Enthusiasts, but I could not determine the app.

Would anyone know which (if any) BusyBox is legitimate?

Comment: [search?q=busybox&c=apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=busybox&c=apps) brings back a ton of results for me.

Comment: @Chahk - right, that's the problem. Which one (if any) is the legitimate app?

Comment: @jww:  What do you mean by "legitimate"?  See also my answer, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either of these:

- [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en)
- [BusyBox Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox.donate&hl=en) (paid)

Note this comment in the description:

> Please note I did not write BusyBox! I wrote this installer and cross
>   compiled BusyBox for Android. Please see the about menu option for
>   more details or here: www.BusyBox.net

If you're installing a custom ROM, it might have BusyBox already (but usually not Pro).

Comment: Another vote for Stericson's apps.  He is quite active on XDA, with a reputation that speaks for itself.

Comment: @geffchang - so I'm clear... BusyBox does not provide a port? If so, then I will try switching up to a BusyBox [prebuilt binary](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/).

Comment: @jww What port are you looking for? Are you looking for a Windows program, or an Android app?

Comment: @geffchang - I was looking for BusyBox's Android app. Here, I'm talking about the the app that the folks at BusyBox produce, not developers with knock-offs that reuse the name. I'm no longer looking, though. I downloaded the ARMv7 build from the BusyBox website. It works fine on my Evo 4G and Transformer tablet.

Comment: I recently updated my BusyBox installer for Android: http://busybox.jrummyapps.com/ The app can be found on GitHub. You can download static binaries there and run a script to compile BusyBox yourself: https://github.com/jrummyapps/BusyBox It would be great if you edited your answer to include this </shamelessplug>

Answer (score 0):

The upstream BusyBox maintainer has probably not uploaded anything official to the Google Play store.  You may choose one of Stericson's (unofficial) BusyBox installers from the Google Play store, or you may grab an official [prebuilt binary](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/) from upstream.  It's your choice.

Note that if you choose a prebuilt binary from upstream, you won't get automatic BusyBox updates in the future.  You'll have to do the updating yourself.